# How bad is it for seo if multiples websites are pointing to same ip-address?

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine, ip-address, web-hosting

I am controlling multiple websites with a same production link on azure. This websites have different domain names but when I try to trace the ip-address of any of those websites the result is same. It is showing the same ip-address for every website which is of the production link. This websites will be having similar content as the actual content will be generated by the users from the same work profession later on using the same admin panel. How can I assign a single ip for a single website either manually or dynamically in azure?

Comment: Your websites are on Auzre VMs or Webapp?

Comment: on webapp @Walter-MSFT